# Retrieve data from Flutter Firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data of all the users of the users collection and compare it with some other data. I am able to retrieve data of a particular user from its uid but  want to iterate through all the collections and documents.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a specific document ID and use the [`get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) method on a [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html), it'll return a [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) (containing all documents in that collection) which essentially is an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html).

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["field_name"]);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "QuerySnapshot" to retrieve data of all the users of the users collection. Please see an example of same at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots

I expect you are currently using "DocumentSnapshot" to retrieve data of a particular user.